# Vagrant - docker-compose file issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am new to VAGRANT - while setting it up - getting bellow issue of docker -

bash: line 4:  5639 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-1.24.1 -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d

```
 [exec] The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
 [exec] Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
 [exec]
 [exec] The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
 [exec] Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
 [exec]
 [exec]  /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-1.24.1  -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d
 [exec]
 [exec] Stdout from the command:
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec]  /usr/local/bin/docker-compose-1.24.1  -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d
```

Where I need to check this file ?
Can anyone help me out? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

run vagrant plugin update commands , it worked for me.